# Mark as 'read' in Google Groups

Tags: google-groups

Is there any way to mark all my Groups, specific Groups or specific threads in a Group as 'read?'

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to do this whilst browsing Google Groups via the web.

It is possible to do this if you subscribe to the groups via [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader).

[image: Mark all read menu - Google Reader]